# Dask Dataframe Mode on groupy?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, dask, dask-dataframe

I am trying to extract the "mode" of a series under a groupby agregation in a dask dataframe. I could find the [documentation of mode](https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/generated/dask.dataframe.DataFrame.mode.html), but not how to use it under a group by.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data = pd.DataFrame({
    'status' :  ['pending', 'pending','pending', 'canceled','canceled','canceled', 'confirmed', 'confirmed','confirmed'],
    'clientId' : ['A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'D', 'C', 'A', 'B','C'],
    'partner' :  ['A', np.nan,'C', 'A',np.nan,'C', 'A', np.nan,'C'],
    'product' : ['afiliates', 'pre-paid', 'giftcard','afiliates', 'pre-paid', 'giftcard','afiliates', 'pre-paid', 'giftcard'],
    'brand' : ['brand_1', 'brand_2', 'brand_3','brand_1', 'brand_2', 'brand_3','brand_1', 'brand_3', 'brand_3'],
    'gmv' : [100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100]})

data = data.astype({'partner':'category','status':'category','product':'category', 'brand':'category'})

import dask.dataframe as dd
df = dd.from_pandas(data,npartitions=1)
df.groupby(['clientId', 'product'], observed=True).aggregate({'brand':'mode'})
df.compute()
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is based on a code provided [here](https://github.com/dask/dask/issues/6329#issuecomment-656699266), with some modifications:

```py
from pandas import DataFrame, Series, NA
from dask.dataframe import from_pandas, Aggregation

data = DataFrame(
    {
        "status": [
            "pending",
            "pending",
            "pending",
            "canceled",
            "canceled",
            "canceled",
            "confirmed",
            "confirmed",
            "confirmed",
        ],
        "clientId": ["A", "B", "C", "A", "D", "C", "A", "B", "C"],
        "partner": ["A", NA, "C", "A", NA, "C", "A", NA, "C"],
        "product": [
            "afiliates",
            "pre-paid",
            "giftcard",
            "afiliates",
            "pre-paid",
            "giftcard",
            "afiliates",
            "pre-paid",
            "giftcard",
        ],
        "brand": [
            "brand_4",
            "brand_2",
            "brand_3",
            "brand_1",
            "brand_2",
            "brand_3",
            "brand_1",
            "brand_3",
            "brand_3",
        ],
        "gmv": [100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100],
    }
)

data = data.astype(
    {
        "partner": "category",
        "status": "category",
        "product": "category",
        "brand": "category",
    }
)
mode_pandas = data.groupby(["clientId", "product"], observed=True).agg(
    {"brand": Series.mode}
)

df = from_pandas(data, npartitions=1)


def chunk(s):
    return s.value_counts()


def agg(s0):
    _intermediate = s0._selected_obj.groupby(level=s0._selected_obj.index.names).sum()
    _intermediate = _intermediate[_intermediate > 0]
    return _intermediate


def finalize(s):
    level = list(range(s.index.nlevels - 1))
    return s.groupby(level=level, group_keys=False).apply(lambda s: s[s == s.max()])


mode = Aggregation(
    name="mode",
    chunk=chunk,
    agg=agg,
    finalize=finalize,
)


mode_dask = df.groupby(["clientId", "product"], observed=True, dropna=True).aggregate(
    {"brand": mode}
).compute()

print(mode_pandas)
print(mode_dask)
```

Note that the `dask` version doesn't yield exactly the same output as `pandas`, but that's an interesting exercise left to the reader.

Comment: Hi! You solution works as "mode" is the only aggregate requested. If I try an "aggregate(
    {"brand": mode, 'product' : 'count'} I get an error " File "index.pyx", line 723, in pandas._libs.index.BaseMultiIndexCodesEngine._extract_level_codes"